# Problems with compiling C++/Cuda code after Linux update

Tags: c++, linux, cuda, automake

We have an in-house C++-code which partly uses CUDA. The CUDA-code is spread between the files "cuda_kernel.hpp" and "cuda_kernel.cu".
All was good and the code compiled both on my local machine and our cluster.

Now I had to update my Linux from impish to jammy, which I did on Friday. When trying to compile said project today I received the following error message:

```
 Making all in dergeraet
 make[1]: Entering directory '/home/paul/Projekte/DerGeraet/dergeraet'
 make  all-am
 make[2]: Entering directory '/home/paul/Projekte/DerGeraet/dergeraet'
 CXX      poisson.o
 make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/include/c++/10/new', needed by 'cuda_kernel.o'.  Stop.
 make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/paul/Projekte/DerGeraet/dergeraet'
 make[1]: *** [makefile:306: all] Error 2
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/paul/Projekte/DerGeraet/dergeraet'
 make: *** [Makefile:374: all-recursive] Error 1
```

So I checked whether nvcc was installed. `nvcc --version` returned nothing so I followed the instructions on https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads to install cuda and then ran `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. Now when calling `nvcc --version` Linux returns

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Nov_18_09:45:30_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5, V11.5.119
Build cuda_11.5.r11.5/compiler.30672275_0
```

Ok, me thinks, let's compile again but the error-message still remains the same.

I checked '/usr/include/c++/10/new' and there is only
'/usr/include/c++/11/new', i.e., no '/usr/include/c++/10' folder.

I am really out of clues here. Tried reinstalling cuda twice with different version numbers (11.6 and 11.7) but the error persisted. Is this some weird incompatibility issues between gcc and nvcc?

Other in-house code (without CUDA) compiles fine, thus I think it must be a cuda-related problem.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Perhaps your build system does not correctly model dependencies? Try wiping out your build folder and do a fresh build from scratch.

Comment: If I call `make clean && make` I get the same error message. Edit: I also tried `autoreconf` and `./configure`  before `make clean && make` but this didn't make a difference either.

Comment: That's not what I said. For all I know, your `make clean` target may be broken and not actually clean everything. What I said was "wipe out your build directory". Might not be your problem, but it doesn't hurt to eliminate possibilities.

Comment: Does the `c++/10` path appear in your environment variables? `printenv | grep c\+\+\/10`

Comment: You have a broken host compiler installation. That missing file is part of libstdc++-10-dev. I would guess you have not installed that, or if you have, it is incomplete. The problem isn't with CUDA. You need a supported version of g++ and libstdc++ and the accompanying headers for nvcc to work correctly. Clearly you currently do not

Comment: `libstdc++-10-dev` indeed this was missing. Thanks! For some reason during the update process gcc-10 was removed or at least some of it was not reachable anymore, I suppose that's why the respective folder was non-existent anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This error was caused by an incomplete host g++ installation. In this case the libstdc++-10-dev package was either missing or incorrectly installed.